# When did the term "space opera" first refer to the SF subgenre, rather than just formulaic, schlocky SF?

Tags: history-of, space-opera

In 1941, [Wilson Tucker](https://sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/tucker_wilson) coined the term "[space opera](https://sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/space_opera)", in parallel with "horse opera" and "soap opera", to refer to schlocky, formulaic writing, the kind of stuff that makes us cautious looking at pulp-era stories.

In the 1950's, an editorial in *Galaxy* ("You will not see this here!") may have confused what was meant by "space opera", but it is clear they were referring to this existing definition: a passage of bad SF was transformed into a bad Western with a suitable substitution of terms.

Fast forward to 1974, when M.John Harrison's space adventure novel *[The Centauri Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Centauri_Device)* was his alleged attempt to put a stake through space opera's heart. If this was his intent, it was clearly unsuccessful: *Star Wars* came out in 1977.

Now, the term is, at worst, neutral.  We use it for space adventures with particular elements: far-future interstellar societies, battles in space, FTL travel and the like. It's a vibrant subgenre with several **really good** recent examples. There are theme anthologies that proudly bear "Space Opera" in the title. And we retrospectively apply it to classics such as the Lensman and Foundation series.

At some point, then, "space opera" went from meaning "schlock" to meaning "a particular type of SF story". When did this happen?

Comment: There was an intermediate period when it was used to scorn the subgenre or refer to guilty pleasures.

Comment: @Mary I think that was Harrison 's mindset, coming out of the British New Wave.

Comment: For some of us, it hasn't happened yet.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron Me_ow_.

Comment: 1941-1977, sci-fi itself was considered illegitimate schlock by larger publishing and producing world; vapid entertainment for nerds. Star Wars was born from Lucas’ love of formulaic schlock Flash Gordon  serials of his childhood and was unable to secure the license to it — to which Universal, UA and Walt Disney wouldn’t touch with 10-ft pole. We guess instead of deciding to pay $10m, Disney figured shelling out $4b 40 years later was the better deal.

Comment: @SillyButTrue This was a term used within the SF community, so what "mainstream" publishers and filmmakers thought isn't really relevant to this question.  But eithin that community, a semantic shift happened, and what I want to know is when that happened.